# Creating unique id for <fieldset> when using form_for Rails Nested Model Form

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a nested model form in the style of this Railscast
http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-revised?view=asciicast

I need to give each  tag a unique ID.  Currently, each field generated has a unique ID and name given by a helper method that assigns a unique ID to every association record.  So that is taken cared of.  However, this form has "fieldset" tags which isn't assigned an ID.  I need a unique ID for each fieldset for jQuery manipulation purposes.

Specifically, how do I do give each fieldset generated for an "Activity" record a unique CSS tag ID?
Posted below is how my form is created. Thank you

**_form.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for(@trip) do |f| %>

<%= f.fields_for :days do |builder| %>
  <%= render 'day_fields', f: builder %>
<% end %>
<%= link_to_add_fields "Add Day", f, :days %>
```

**_day_fields.html.erb partial**

```
<fieldset>
  <%= f.label :summary, "Day Summary" %><br />
  <%= f.text_area :summary, :rows => 1 %><br />
    <%= link_to "remove", '#', class: "remove_fields" %>

  <%= f.fields_for :activities do |builder| %>
    <%= render 'activity_fields', f: builder %>
  <% end %>
  <%= link_to_add_fields "Add Activity", f, :activities %>
</fieldset>
```

**_activity_fields.html.erb**

```
<fieldset>
  <%= f.label :title, "Activity" %><br />
  <%= f.text_field :title, :rows => 1 %><br />
  <%= f.hidden_field :_destroy %>
  <%= link_to "remove", '#', class: "remove_fields" %>
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using ryanb nested_form gem :

Use `f.index` instead. And make sure that you pass every different form_builder in your partials.

For example if you do

```
<%= main_form.fields_for :nested1_items do |nested1_form| %>
    <%= render partial 'main/nested1_fields', nested1_form: nested1_form %>
<% end %>
```

*_nested1_fields*

```
<fieldset id="nested1-<%= nested1_form.index %>-items">
```

See my answer [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15782006/rails-nested-form-assign-unique-id-to-generated-field/26864291#26864291).

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use the `f.object` passed in to both partials?

```
<% fieldset_id = "#{f.object.class.underscore}_#{f.object.id}" %>
<fieldset id='<%= fieldset_id %>'>
...
```

Comment: Ah I should've mentioned that new fieldsets are being generated via Ajax calls and loaded up. So, your method works when I edit a Form but when I create new fields, the object.id is empty so this doesn't work.  Any ideas here? @RyanBigg

Comment: @HungLuu ya find another way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue, and I solve it using the time in seconds, and pass it to every where I needed.

For example:

in the **controller**

```
def something
  # First idea
  @dynid = Time.now.to_i
  ...
  # Second idea: store it in the session
  session[:dynid] = Time.now.to_i
  ...
end
```

in your **view**

```
<fieldset id="#{@dynid}">
<!-- or in case @dynid is out of reach, then use the session[:dynid] -->
<fieldset id="#{session[:dynid]}">
```

The `session[:dynid}` will still works even with ajax rendered code.

I hope this helps you.

Comment: I'm sorry - I don't really understand the concept of storing session[:dynid] in a session. I tried just putting it in ERB but it was generating the same ID for every ajax added form partial.

Comment: I use `session[:dynid]` to store a unique number to wich i can refference. In your case, you can use it to generate the ID of the fieldsets.