# rails nested form assign unique id to generated field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-forms

I want to assign unique Id to each row generated by nested form .

I looked this question [Creating unique id for <fieldset> when using form_for Rails Nested Model Form](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13189689/1970061) but this doesn't solve my problem .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, the solution given by Anil Maurya only works for items that have been dynamically added via javascript using `link_to_add` provided by the gem. But for me, it would leave `new_association` for already existing items.

In order to properly identify every nested element (even the deeply nested ones), it is possible to use `f.index`. The advantage is that if the entry already exists (meaning, if it was in the database), then it will just be replaced by the index that it has in the array. However, using `link_to_add` will replace `f.index` by the ID automatically generated by nested_form, just like Anil Maurya's solution.

For deeply nested solutions, instead of just writing `fields_for` and using the same variable `f` everytime, if you need to properly tag your elements, your should specify which partial to render and each time use a different `f` variable, which you should pass to the partial

For example: if you have

```
Main has_many :nested1s
Nested1 has_many :nested2s
Nested2 has_many :nested3s
```

Then your code should look like this (I gave an example with tables because it's more difficult):

```
<%= nested_form_for @Main do |main_form| %>
<table>
    <thead>
        <stuff />
    </thead>
    <%= main_form.fields_for :nested1s, :wrapper => false do |nested1_f| %>
        <%= render 'main/nested1_fields', nested1_f: nested1_f %>
    <% end %>
```

*_nested1_fields.html.erb*

```
<tbody class="fields">
    <tr>Stuff</tr>
    <tr>
        <table id="nested1-<%= nested1_f.index %>-nested2s">
        <thead>Stuff</thead>
        <%= nested1_f.fields_for :nested2s, :wrapper => false do |nested2_f| %>
            <%= render 'main/nested2_fields', nested1_f: nested1_f, nested2_f: nested2_f %>
        <% end %>
        </table>
    </tr>
    <tr><%= nested1_f.link_to_add 'add nested2', :nested2, :data => { :target => "#nested1-#{nested1_f.index}-nested2s"}, class: "btn btn-sm btn-success" %>
</tbody>
```

*_nested2_fields.html.erb*

```
<tbody class="fields">
...
    <table id="nested1-<%= nested1_f.index %>-nested2-<%= nested2_f.index %>-nested3s">
       <%= fields_for :nested3s do |nested3_f| %>
       ...
...
</tbody>
```

Also it is important to note that the gem nested_form will only work well if every nested fieldsets are wrapped by a tag with the class "fields"

Comment: Thanks. It took me quite some time to figure this out for my own project. Actually I found the `f.index` in the Rails API doc. It should only work for rails 4+, but there is another way to do this for older versions using `f.options[:child_index]`. See this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4853373/rails-fields-for-with-index

Answer (score 3):

I managed to solve this problem by looking into nested form gem .
Inside nested gem unique Id is generated for each addition dynamically.
data-blueprint is parsed and "new_#{association}" is replaced with generated unique ID.In my case relation was like 'Catalogues' has_many 'Category' so my association was categories.
I assigned new row with id = "new_categories" and its replaced by unique Id when new row is added.

Maybe its useful some one else.

Comment: how to permit the new_tags in rails4? should I just permit it?

Comment: Could you post the link to the code or be more explicit ? Doesn't work for me and I'm very interested in your solution :)

Comment: Oh sorry, Just realised I was using the wrong association name ^^". It must be the name of the current partial (_association_fields) with the "s" Thanks you for your solution it works !

Comment: @CyrilDD glad that it worked for you as well, happy coding :)

Comment: Actually, I just realised this solution doesn't work as intended :( I'll post another answer explaining why.