# Rails assign ids to elements in builder to access using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I'm using the Rails builder to build multiple `:pay` objects

```
<%= f.fields_for :pay do |builder| %>                            

    <%= render "non_taxable_pays", :f => builder %> 

<% end %>
```

This is rendering `_taxable_pays` multiple times as desired

> **_taxable_pays.html.erb**

```
<div class="row">
    <%= f.hidden_field :employee_id %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :ee_pay_id %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :pay_sub_head_id %> 
    <div class="col-md-5">
      <div class="col-md-5">
        <div class="form_indent1"><div class="form_indent1"><%= f.object.ee_pay.company_pay.description %></div></div>
            <div class="form_spacer"></div>
        </div>      

        <div class="col-md-7">
          <div class="form_indent1"><span>€ </span><%= f.text_field :rate, value: number_to_currency(f.object.rate), class: "currency_input" %></div>
          <div class="form_spacer"></div>
        </div>      
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-7">      

        <div class="col-md-4">  
          <div class="form_indent1"><%= f.text_field :amount, value: number_to_currency(f.object.amount, :unit => ""), class: "number_input" %></div>
          <div class="form_spacer"></div><br />
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <div class="form_indent1"><%= f.object.ee_pay.company_pay.units %></div>
          <div class="form_spacer"></div>
        </div> 
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <div class="form_indent1"><span>€ </span><%= number_to_currency(f.object.rate*f.object.amount) %></div>
          <div class="form_spacer"></div>
        </div>                  

    </div>  
</div>
```

My issue is in the partial `_taxable_pays` above. In the last section I have code that displays the value * the rate `f.object.rate*f.object.amount`. This is great when the page is first displayed as it calculates it based on the values in the database.

I'm now looking to dynamically update this field using jQuery if the user changes the values in the text_fields holding the `:rate` or `:amount`. But for the life of me I can't figure out how I should assign id's to the different renders or access them using jQuery.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks for looking

Comment: Anyone? I'm stumped on how to go about this

Answer (score 0):

So this post helped me come up with my solution

[Creating unique id for <fieldset> when using form_for Rails Nested Model Form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13189689/creating-unique-id-for-fieldset-when-using-form-for-rails-nested-model-form)

I put this at the top of the `_taxable_pays` partial

```
<% partial_type = "#{f.object.class}" %>
<% partial_id = "#{f.object.id}" %>
```

and I was then able to assign ids to the desired elements such as

```
<span id="<%= "#{partial_type}-value-#{partial_id}" %>
```

Might help someone in the future